# Changing and deleting files and directories from hard drive that was connected to a Solaris 9 system/computer

Tags: kubuntu, solaris

I have files and directories in a IDE hard drive that was installed in a Solaris 9 computer.

I have to delete and copy to that hard some files and directories to it, but all I can do it is to read and copy from it to my computer. I understood that it is a permissions issue, but I don't know how to overcome it.

- I use: Kubuntu 18.10. I can attach the hard drive and see its contents.
- I tried to open Krusader as root and then tried to delete or rename and copy to the hard drive, but it didn't work.
- I also tried to change the permissions with pcManfm file manager

Can anyone help with detailed steps because I'm not very familiar with Unix or Linux commands. If it helps I tried the command `fdisk -l` :

```
inspiron@inspiron-pc:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
[sudo] password for inspiron: 
Disk /dev/sdb: 301.7 GiB, 323928170496 bytes, 632672208 sectors
Geometry: 16 heads, 255 sectors/track, 57459 cylinders
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: sun

Device         Start        End    Sectors    Size   Id     Type       Flags
/dev/sdb1   20971200   41942399   20971200     10G    2  SunOS root
/dev/sdb2          0   20971199   20971200     10G    3  SunOS swap    u 
/dev/sdb3          0   34432719  234432720  111.8G    5  Whole disk      
/dev/sdb7   41942400   42023999      81600   39.9M    0  Unassigned      
/dev/sdb8   42024000  234432719  192408720   91.8G    8  SunOS home
```

The device I want to work on is sdb8.

Comment: Have you tried to mount `/dev/sda8` via the command line? what is the output of `sudo file -sL /dev/sda8` ?

Comment: /dev/sda8: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=ffc9acf4-a82d-4ad5-b5a6-eef7e34d1286 (needs journal recovery) (extents) (64bit) (large files) (huge files)

Comment: Do you get any error messages when you simply try `sudo mount /dev/sdb8 /mnt`? If so [edit] your question to add the information.